# Mock service in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, testing, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I have a problem with mocking service in Spring MVC:

```
@Controller
public class CompanyController {

  @Autowired
  private CompanyService companyService;

  @Autowired
  private CompanyRelationService companyRelationService;

  @GetMapping({"/", "/companies"})
  public String displayCompanies(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("company", new Company());
    List<Company> companies = companyService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("companies", companies);
    return "companies";
  }
}
```

and test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CompanyTests {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Mock
CompanyService companyServiceMock;

private MockMvc mockMvc;


@Before
public void setUp() {
    Mockito.reset(companyServiceMock);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}


@Test
public void shouldListAllCompanies() throws Exception {
    Company company1 = new Company("company1", new Address());
    Company company2 = new Company("company2", new Address());

    when(companyServiceMock.findAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(company1, company2));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/companies"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("companies"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("companies", hasSize(2)))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("companies", hasItem(
                    allOf(
                            hasProperty("name", is("company1")))
            )))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("companies", hasItem(
                    allOf(
                            hasProperty("name", is("company2"))
                    )
            )));

}
}
```

The question is why I get companies from real service instead of mock (company1, company2):

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'companies'
     Expected: a collection containing (hasProperty("name", is "company1"))
     but: hasProperty("name", is "company1") property 'name' was "companyFromRealService", 
     hasProperty("name", is "company1") property 'name' was "CompanyFromRealService2"
```

Updated Test class, removed setUp and changed @Bean into @MockBean, but remain @SpringBootTest and it works:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CompanyTests {

@MockBean
private CompanyService companyServiceMock;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
@WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
public void shouldListAllCompanies() throws Exception {
    Company company1 = new Company("company1", new Address());
    Company company2 = new Company("company2", new Address());

    when(companyServiceMock.findAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(company1, company2));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/companies"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("companies"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("companies", hasSize(2)))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("companies", hasItem(
                    allOf(
                            hasProperty("name", is("companyFromRealService1")))
            )))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("companies", hasItem(
                    allOf(
                            hasProperty("name", is("companyFromRealService2"))
                    )
            )));
}
```

}

Comment: What happens on the `get("/companies")`? I guess it calls real service. Replace the call with mock results

Comment: Ofcourse they won't... You are working against the framework. Spring Boot does a lot of work injecting and mocking the dependencies and the first thing you do is destroy all that work. Remove your `@Before` method and put `@Autowired` on the `MockMvc` field and restart your test.

Comment: @StanislavL how can i do that?

Comment: @M.Deinum No beans of MockMvc type found

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using? Add `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` to your test class.

Comment: Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE

Comment: @M.Deinum ok, now there is no error No beans of MockMvc type found, but there is still a problem with getting data from real service instead of mock.

Comment: You have removed your `@Before` method?

Comment: yes, i removed it.

Comment: Replace `@Mock` with `@MockBean` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you are just testing controller slice of your application, you should use `@WebMvcTest` annotation instead of `@SpringBootTest` (you can find more information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests)). You can use it like this : `@WebMvcTest(CompanyController.class)`.

Secondly why are you getting into trouble with `MockMvc` in `setUp()` method? You can erase that `setUp` method as people suggest in comments and `@Autowire` MockMvc.

Finally, as you are using spring boot, it is better to use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock` which is a wrapped version of it inside the spring library.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I did it and now i have java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext error.

Comment: @Helosze, Can you update your answer with the current test class?

Comment: When I changed Mock to MockBean, but didn't change SpringBootTest into WebMvcTest, now it works

Comment: @Helosze, happy to help. You may still want to update your test class final form to your question, so people can see it easly in the future if they end up in this question. And you can accept this answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Yes, of course. I've edited it. But maybe it will be good to change this SpringBootTest into WebMvcTest? :) Thanks for your help!