# How to get result from not mocked method?

Tags: java, spring, testing, mocking, mockito

I have a problem with getting result from method which is not mocked. I dont want to mock the result but to achieve the real result from this method. The method works in application, so this is not the problem. I have a test:

```
    @Test
public void shouldGetCompaniesToSelect() throws Exception {
    Company company = new Company("company", new Address());
    Company relatedCompany1 = new Company("relatedCompanyName1", new Address());
    Company notRelatedCompany = new Company("notRelatedCompanyName", new Address());
    Company relatedCompany2 = new Company("relatedCompanyName2", new Address());
    CompanyRelation companyRelation1 = new CompanyRelation(relatedCompany1);
    CompanyRelation companyRelation2 = new CompanyRelation(relatedCompany2);
    company.getCompanyRelations().add(companyRelation1);
    company.getCompanyRelations().add(companyRelation2);

    when(companyServiceMock.findAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList
            (company, relatedCompany1, notRelatedCompany, relatedCompany2));
    when(companyServiceMock.findOne(1L)).thenReturn(company);

    List<Company> companiesToSelect =  companyServiceMock.findCompaniesToSelect(company);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/company/1"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("companiesToSelect", hasSize(1)))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("companiesToSelect", hasItem(
                    hasProperty("relatedCompany", hasProperty(
                            "name", is("notRelatedCompanyName")
                    )))));
}
```

There are 2 mocked methods (findAll and findOne) and then I want to execute method and get real results from findCompaniesToSelect(company - this is object created to test). Size of the companiesToSelect should be 1, but it returns 0.

findCompaniesToSelect method:

```
public List<Company> findCompaniesToSelect(Company company) {
    List<Company> companiesToSelect = companyRepository.findAll();
    for (CompanyRelation companyRelation :
            company.getCompanyRelations()) {
        companiesToSelect.remove(companyRelation.getRelatedCompany());
    }
    companiesToSelect.remove(company);
    return companiesToSelect;
}
```

How can I do that?

EDIT 1:

Okay, so I've changed it into @Spy and changed stubs into:

```
    Mockito.doReturn(Arrays.asList(company, relatedCompany1, 
    notRelatedCompany, relatedCompany2)).when(companyServiceMock).findAll();
    Mockito.doReturn(company).when(companyServiceMock).findOne(1L);
```

But when I run the test, the findCompaniesToSelect() method is using real companies instead of mocked companies.

Okay, so now the problem is when the findCompaniesToSelect() method is called, the companyRepository.findAll method is called. I want to call mocked findAll method from test to get mocked companies instead of real companies.

EDIT 2:

Okay, the problem was because findCompaniesToSelect() method uses repository, not a service. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a combination of mocked methods and real method calls on an object then you need to use a spy instead of a mock.

```
@Spy
CompanyService companyServiceSpy
```

You will need to stub your mock methods differently though. using doReturn(...).when(...) instead of the stubbing you are currently using.

Have a look at http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy for more information on using spies.

**EDIT:** Since you are mocking some behaviour in your test you should use a standalone set up for your MockMvc object and inject the mock into your controller like so:

```
MockMvc mockMvc;

@Spy
CompanyService companyServiceSpy;

@InjectMocks
CompanyController companyController;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(companyController).build();
}
```

**EDIT 2:** You may also be able to resolve this just by changing @Spy to @SpyBean in your current set up. Not 100% sure on this because i'm not fully familiar with how Spring boot sets up tests.

Comment: I've added new post

Comment: So CompanyService is a @Controller??

Comment: Nope. CompanyController is using CompanyService with method findCompaniesToSelect().

Comment: it's Autowired, SpringBoot.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how Spring boot sets up the mockMvc object for you. But it should be a standalone setup where you put in a reference to your Controller class decorated with the @InjectMocks annotation. Might be worth not using the one Spring boot provides.

Comment: It's not the problem - the problem is when the findCompaniesToSelect() method is called, the companyRepository.findAll method is called. I want to call mocked findAll method from test to get mocked companies instead of real companies. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, with your stubs set up it shouldn't be calling the real findAll method but I think what is happening is that the spy isn't getting injected into your controller at all because of the way the mockMvc is set up so that your mocks do nothing.

Comment: I've created the topic yesterday about setting up MockMvc in SpringBoot and I think my configuration is good:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795854/mock-service-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Yeah so using a webAppContext set up for your MockMvc is more of an integration test. But since you are mocking behaviour you should use a standalone set up for the MockMvc and don't use the @WebMvcTest annotation because this sets you up with a webAppContext one. Ill update my answer with details in a sec

Comment: Finally i'm not using @WebMvcTest, because there was something wrong with that.

Comment: Sorry I meant dont use @AutoConfigureMockMvc

Comment: Editting again actually. You might be able to solve this just by using `@SpyBean` instead of `@Spy`

Comment: I'm already using Spy, because there was an error with SpyBean, exactly like Mock and MockBean in my previous topic.

Comment: It looks like from your previous topic @MockBean was the one that worked?

Comment: But now i realized that it doesn't work, because in findCompaniesToSelect() method it uses repository, not service.

Comment: Ah haha, that'll be it. I was getting very confused then

Comment: I've changed it to just findAll() in service, but now there is an error:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Or when I create new MockBean to repository and stub it, there is the same error

Comment: That seems odd but I think it might be out the scope of the original question now.

Comment: Still I can't get the right result from this method. :D

Comment: Okay, there was a problem with Arrays.asList(). Now everything works. :) Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it! Good luck with the rest of your project. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your service class i.e. companyService is mocked.
I should suggested to use **Restassured** for testing your Restservice, where it didn't require to create mock for different methods of your RestService components i.e. you don't need to mock CompanyService.

For further reading:

[RestAssured](http://rest-assured.io/)

[Example Code for RestAssured testing](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/07/04/integration-testing-a-spring-boot-application/)